# Doubt in Heine-Borel Theorem proof in Axler's MIRA book

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am studying the proof of the Heine-Borel Theorem (Every open cover of a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a finite subcover) in Axler's "Measure, Integration and Real Analysis": I have understood the proof except for a passage.

The proof is as follows:

Suppose $F$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is an open cover of $F$. First consider the case where $F=[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R},\ a<b$. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$. Let $D=\{d\in [a,b]:[a,d]\text{ has a finite subcover from }\mathcal{C}\}$. Note that $a\in D$ (because $a\in G$ for some $G\in\mathcal{C}$). Thus $D$ is not the empty set. Let $s=\sup D$. Thus $s\in [a,b]$. Hence there exists an open set $G\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $s\in G$. Let $\delta>0$ be such that $(s-\delta,s+\delta)\subset G$.

**Because $s=\sup D$, there exists $d\in (s-\delta,s]$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $G_1,\dots, G_n\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $[a,d]\subset G_1\cup\dots\cup G_n$.**

My doubt is about this last sentence: I don't understand why $d\in (s-\delta,s]$ instead of $d\in (s-\delta,s)$ (since it could also be that $s\notin D$).

I would be grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: If $d \in (s-\delta,s)$ then $d \in (s-\delta,s]$. That $s$ is the sup of $D$ means that $D \cap (s-\delta,s]$ is nonempty. But if (it doesn’t happen here but it’s possible to consider it) $D=\{a,a+1\}$, then $a+1$ is the sup of $D$ even though $D \cap (a,a+1)=\emptyset$.

Comment: In general if you have a non-empty bounded set $A$ of real numbers and $\alpha=\sup A$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, the number $\alpha-\epsilon$ is NOT an upper bound of $A$ (otherwise it would contradict $\alpha$ being the supremum). Thus, there exists an $a\in A$ such that $\alpha -\epsilon < a$ (but trivially $a\leq \alpha=\sup A$). Hence, $\alpha-\epsilon<a\leq \alpha$. We need the weak-inequality on the right; that in general cannot be strengthened to a strict inequality. But anyway, the weak inequality is all you need.

Comment: @Mindlack ah, I see, thank you very much; if one of you would write your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah, I see, thank you very much; if one of you would write your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it